# Repunits whose digits in base $b$ are all $b-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

Positive integers whose base-$b$ representation contains only the digit $1$ are called repunits in that base. But what about positive integers whose base-$b$ representation contains only the digit $b-1$?

For instance, how would one call the base-$20$ number whose representation in that base is 
$$19\cdot19\cdot19\cdot19\cdot19_{20}?$$

Is there a special name for this kind of number? I know repunits are useful in many number-theoretical contexts, but what about such numbers?

Comment: You mean like 99999 in base 10?

Comment: Probably not. They can be written as $b^{k}-1.$

Answer (score 1):

While there is no name, to my knowledge, for the general case, they are referred to as Mersenne numbers for base 2.